# AngularJs send value to Struts2

Tags: java, angularjs, post, struts2, carousel

i am having some problems to receive a value from angularJS in struts2 action.

The objective is to receive the index of the current image in a carousel.

**selectArm.jsp**

```
var app = angular.module('menuAPP', ['ui.bootstrap']);
        app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, $window, $location) {
            $scope.hideError=true;
            $scope.show = function() {


                $scope.currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;//Carousel index
                var params = "NSlider :"+ $scope.currentIndex;
                var data = angular.toJson(params)
                $http({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'showArm',
                    data: 'NSlider =' + data
                }).success(function(response)
                {
                    post("formShowBrazo");
                });
            };
```

**ArmAction.java**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class BrazoAction implements Action 
{
private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(BrazoAction.class);
private String NSlider;

public String execute() throws Exception {

    HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession();

    session.setAttribute("forward","sBrazo");
    String aux = NSlider.split(":")[1]; //Receive "NSlider : {int}"
    session.setAttribute("id_brazo", aux);
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String getNSlider() {
    return NSlider;
}

public void setNSlider(String NSlider) {
    this.nSlider = NSlider;
}
```

}

This jsp must show the index of selected picture in the carousel.

**showArm.jsp**

```
<body>
    <script src="lib/threejs/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/threejs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/threejs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/threejs/stats.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/webGL.js"></script>      
    <%
        out.println(session.getAttribute("id_brazo"));
    %>
    <div id='container' width=800, height=600>  
</body>
```

If I debug the action, I can see that i don't receive any value from angular.

**UPDATE**
Changed the json petition, changed the name of get and set and also changed to string the parameter.

Now i receive null value. Still not working well.

**UPDATE 2**
Now show the final result. Now works fine.

Comment: Change your getter and setter to `setNSlider` or change variable name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how i pass data to Struts action  please take reference from this.

```js
$scope.submitForm = function() {

        var params = {
            "name" : $scope.name,
            "username" : $scope.username,
            "email" : $scope.email
        };

        var data = angular.toJson(params);
        $http( {
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/angular/studentForm.action',
            data : 'value=' + data,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            if (data.errors) {
                $scope.errorname = data.errors.name;
                $scope.errorUsername = data.errors.username;
                $scope.erroremail = data.errors.email;
            } else {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.message = data;

            }
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            return false;
        });
    };
});
```

You have  to change the parameter to string because angular js only works with json data.

Comment: please pass the value same name as you want to get in action class, here  you are passing  parameter named as value and want to get in NSlider.. Try it.... 
 $http({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'showArm',
                    data: 'NSlider=' + data
                }).success(function(response)
                {
                    post("formShowBrazo");
                });

Comment: IT WORKED. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module("ProductApp", []);
angular.module("ProductApp").controller("ProController",

        function($scope, $window, $log, $http) {
            $log.debug("loading controller");
            $scope.productModel = {
                'name' : '',
                'type' : '',
                'company' : '',
                'price' : 0
            };
            $scope.toServer = function() {
                $log.debug('starting to server');
                var httpJson = {
                    url : '/angular_firstlook/product',
                    method : "POST",
                    params : {
                        'product' : $scope.productModel
                    }
                };
                $http(httpJson).success(function() {
                    $window.alert("sent to server success");
                    //geeting data from server
                }).error(function() {
                    $window.alert("sent to server failure");
                });
            };
        });
```

Comment: This is how i am sending  data to controller class Can anyone tell me how to retrieve